# Creating a right skewed binary tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree, treenode, adjustment

In this program, the user should be able to create an arbitrary binary tree from a sequence of input integers and they should be able select between to `balanced`, `left_only`, `right_only`. I created it for balanced binary tree, but now I am unable to adjust it to right  only and left only tree.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct tree {
    struct node* root;
};

int init(struct tree* t) {
    t->root = 0;
    return 1;
}

struct node* makeNode(int d) {
    struct node* ptr;
    ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data = d;
    ptr->left = ptr->right = 0;
    return ptr;
}

// sorting the binary tree
struct node* insertrchild(struct node* n, int d) {
    return (n->right = makeNode(d));
}
struct node* insertlchild(struct node* n, int d) {
    return (n->left = makeNode(d));
}

struct node* insertbst(struct node** ptr, int d) {
    if (*ptr == 0)
        return (*ptr = makeNode(d));
    if (d > (*ptr)->data)
        insertbst(&(*ptr)->right, d);
    else
        insertbst(&(*ptr)->left, d);
}

void inorder(struct node* ptr) // Print Tree
{ // Perform Inorder Traversal of tree
    if (ptr == 0) {
        return;
    }
    inorder(ptr->left);
    printf(" %d ", ptr->data);
    inorder(ptr->right);
}

void preorder(struct node* ptr) {
    if (ptr == 0)
        return;
    printf("%i\t", ptr->data);
    preorder(ptr->left);
    preorder(ptr->right);
}

void postorder(struct node* ptr) {
    if (ptr == 0)
        return;
    postorder(ptr->left);
    postorder(ptr->right);
    printf("%i\t", ptr->data);
}
```

How do I adjust this code?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that balances your tree; the balance (or unbalance) of the tree is controlled solely by the order in which the nodes are presented for insertion into the tree.

Comment: I have code for balancing. i used the DSW balancing algorithm which is not included here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary tree, as I always understood that structure (maybe, I am totally wrong), has an order. Each new element, less than current node, goes to left. Each node, greater than current node goes to right. Or vice versa.
In your example you have functions that put new node on the left or on the right. So what's the problem? Call right insert and you will have right vine, call left insert and you will have left vine, but there would be no sense (IMHO).
Usually, balanced binary tree is a result of insertion of good distributed values (hence, shuffled). For example, insert 10, 7, 9, 12, 6

[image]

If you insert ordered set you will make a vine. For example 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,14

[image]

Also, you can make something like

[image]

if insert 10, 50, 15, 45, 20, 35, 30, 34, 31 (ordered and unordered sets,  one after another). It is, like vine, has O(n) for search.

Comment: You had fun with the diagrams!

Comment: I have one big diagram of binary trees for all cases and have to cut it for different questions

Comment: @IvanIvanov, really? then what is Binary search tree? a dequeue? AFAIK the binary tree has no order.